# Cannot access a disposed object in instance VB.net

Tags: vb.net

i have problem with my project, i have 2 form, 1 form with `MDI container = true` and 1 form is child form. 
i have code in parent form like below

```
   Public Class frmInduk
    Dim afrmDaftarBarang As frmDaftarBarang = frmDaftarBarang.instance
    Private Sub DataBarangToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataBarangToolStripMenuItem.Click

        With afrmDaftarBarang
            .MdiParent = Me
            'Dim afrmDaftarBarang As frmDaftarBarang = frmDaftarBarang.instance
            .Show()
            .Focus()

        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

and than, in my child form i have code like below

```
Public Class frmDaftarBarang
Private Shared anInstance As frmDaftarBarang
Public Shared ReadOnly Property instance() As frmDaftarBarang
    Get
        If anInstance Is Nothing Then
            anInstance = New frmDaftarBarang

        End If
        Return anInstance

    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

when i run this project, it no problem . my project can run very well. but the truble come when i call `frmDataBarang`, and then i close, but when i call `frmDataBarang` again 
i get some error lice picture bellow

[image]

i hope anybody can help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the Singleton pattern, but you did it imperfectly.  An MDI child form can be created more than once, you will have to set the singleton instance back to Nothing when it gets destroyed.  Do so with the FormClosing event:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosed(ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    anInstance = Nothing
    MyBase.OnFormClosed(e)
End Sub
```

You will also need to do something reasonable when an existing instance is displayed again.  It might not be in the right state.  This code *really* belongs in the MDI parent, but you can limp along with this:

```
    Get
        If anInstance Is Nothing Then
            anInstance = New frmDaftarBarang
        Else
            If anInstance.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
                anInstance.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
            End If
        End If
        Return anInstance
```

Do note that this gets ugly when you use the singleton to do things other than child activation.  It is really rather a bad idea to use the pattern.  It is fine on your MdiParent, there can only ever be one parent and when it gets closed then the program terminates anyway.  But those same rules don't apply to a child.  Move child instance management code to the parent class, that's where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

When your class is called a second time, the instance is not `Nothing`, because it still exists, in a disposed state. You must add a check to see whether it is disposed.

This may work:

```
Public Class frmDaftarBarang
Private Shared anInstance As frmDaftarBarang
Public Shared ReadOnly Property instance() As frmDaftarBarang
    Get
        If anInstance Is Nothing OrElse anInstance.IsDisposed Then
            anInstance = New frmDaftarBarang

        End If
        Return anInstance

    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

Comment: thanks Frosty840, but its still not work, 
still in same error, 
maybe you have any idea ?

Comment: You don't appear to ever actually call frmDaftarBarang.instance. Therefore that code will never be executed. Try looking up some tutorials about how to implement Singleton pattern in VB.net.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to show the disposed form just create a new one each time.

```
Dim newForm as New frmDaftarBarang
newForm.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if form you're calling causes exception.

In this case fix any errors in form load and show events in form you are calling.